# fullpage.js removing event listener after reBuild()

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I try to use fullpage.js on this site https://frontendsite.bitbucket.io/#twoPage. There is collapsible content in section #twoPage.

I'm initilize fullpage plugin

```
var myFullpage;
function initFullPage() {
myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage',{

 navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    scrollOverflow: true,
    scrollOverflowOptions: {click: false},
      scrollOverflowReset: true,
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
      var loadedSection = $(this);
      var nextSection = loadedSection.next();
      var prevSection = loadedSection.prev();
      if(nextSection.hasClass('fp-auto-height') ) {
        var IScroll = nextSection.find('.fp-scrollable').data('iscrollInstance');
        IScroll.scrollTo(0, 0, 0)
      }
      if(prevSection.hasClass('fp-auto-height') ) {
        var IScroll = prevSection.find('.fp-scrollable').data('iscrollInstance');
        IScroll.scrollTo(0, IScroll.maxScrollY, 0)
      }
  },
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'twoPage', '3rdPage', 'foursPage'],

 });

}
```

I add click listener in purpose of show/hide collapsible content via jQuery

```
$('.plus_icon.question').click(function( ){
      var a = $(this).siblings('.answer');
      a.toggleClass('open');
      $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
      myFullpage.reBuild();
    });
```

But after one time show/hide of collapsible content with ".answer" click callback doesn't work, but it works if I comment line with myFullPage.reBuild(). Is it bug of fullpage.js or I aplly plugin incorrectly?

Comment: Have you addressed the licensing issue which creates an error in the console: fullpage.extensions.min.js:8 fullPage: Fullpage.js version 3 has changed its license to GPLv3 and it requires a `licenseKey` option. Read about it here: ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember you'll need to get a fullPage.js license in order to use it legally.

Second. You can use the `afterRebuild` callback:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage',{
    afterRender: function(){
         bindMyEvents();
    },
    afterReBuild: function(){
        bindMyEvents();
    }
});

function bindMyEvents(){
    $('.plus_icon.question').click(function( ){
      var a = $(this).siblings('.answer');
      a.toggleClass('open');
      $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
      myFullpage.reBuild();
    });
}
```

Or, easier to just use jquery event delegation:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage',{OPTIONS HERE});

$(document).on('click, '.plus_icon.question', function( ){
  var a = $(this).siblings('.answer');
  a.toggleClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
  myFullpage.reBuild();
});
```